# Does $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(a+i)^b}$ converge for $b>1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(a+i)^b}$$ converge for $b>1$? What is the name of this series?

Comment: I do not know of a name if $a\ne 0$. But if the terms are well-defined, we have convergence by limit comparison with a $p$-series. These are $\sum \frac{1}{i^p}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might helps: when $\Re s>1,\ \Re q>0$, the [Hurwitz zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) is defined by
$$\zeta(s,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+q)^{-s}.$$
This sequence is absolutely convergent for the given $s,q$, and its domain can be extended to $\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$ by analytic continuation. In particular,
$$\zeta(s,1)=\zeta(s).$$

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{(a+i)^b}\sim \dfrac{1}{i^b}$.....

Answer (score 1):

The summand is a decreasing function, so you can compare it to the corresponding integral = $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(a+x)^b}$ and check that it converges.

Answer (score 1):

Almost from definition of Hurwitz Zeta function  $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(a+i)^b}=\zeta (b,a+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Almost from definition of Hurwitz Zeta function  $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(a+i)^b}=\zeta (b,a+1)$$ which is absolutely convergent.